# R, order of filtering when querying from a SQL database

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, dbi

I am trying to extract a subset of a table located in a SQL database, and the result I get is different depending on the order of applied filters.

I need to apply three filters, say "YEAR %in% years", "SYSTEM != 'G'", and "CODE == code".

I've tried putting all three conditions into the SQL statement:

```
table1 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = connection, 
  statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (",
                     paste0(years, collapse = ","), ") AND SYSTEM != 'G'" AND CODE = ", code))
```

But the output I got was an empty table.

Then I tried putting two of the conditions into the statement, and then filtering the output using the third condition:

```
table2 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = connection, 
  statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (",
                     paste0(years, collapse = ","), ") AND SYSTEM != 'G'")) %>%
  filter(CODE == code)

table3 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = connection, 
  statement = paste0("SELECT * FROM database WHERE SYSTEM != 'G' AND CODE = ", code)) %>%
  filter(YEAR %in% years)
```

As a result, table2 contained 914 rows, while table3 contained 184 rows, even though the results should be exactly the same.

I expected the results from each of the three code chunks to be the same, so I'm a bit lost as to what the issue might be.

Comment: You really shouldn't inject your data into your query, instead use proper parameterization. Let's see if escaping or parameterization makes a difference

Comment: More info about params: In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterized (and safer) version of your query:

```r
years <- 2022:2024
qry <- paste("SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (",
             paste(rep("?", length(years)), collapse = ","),
             ") AND SYSTEM != 'G' AND CODE = ?")
qry
# [1] "SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN ( ?,?,? ) AND SYSTEM != 'G' AND CODE = ?"

table <- dbGetQuery(conn = connection, statement = qry, params = c(years, list(code)))
```

One might go a step further and parameterize the constant `'G'` in your query. If it's always `'G'`, then you should be okay, but if that is determined externally then it should also be parameterized.

Note that the alignment of `?` in the query must align perfectly with the data in the `params=` list. If one needs to use the same variable multiple times in the SQL query, then it must appear multiple times in the `params` list, in the correct order with all other parameters to be bound. The `params=` list cannot include unused values. While all of this might sound over-constraining and/or complicated, it is really meant for the protection of the query *and is worth it*. Too many times I've had a (non-parameterized) query mysteriously break with no clear clue, due to ANSI or unquoted spaces or something similar. (Fortunately, it's always only broken the query and never corrupted a table.)

Comment: Thanks so much, using a parameterized query worked! I'm quite new to using SQL, so I had no idea parameterized queries existed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with charlieface that you should ideally use parameterised queries, but try this for the time being:

```
# If CODE is varchar: code => character scalar
code <- '0001'

# Try this: table1 => data.frame
table1 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = connection, 
  statement = paste0(
    "SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (",
    paste0(
      years, 
      collapse = ","
    ), 
    ") AND SYSTEM != 'G' AND CODE = '", 
    code,
    "'"
  )
)

# If CODE is an integer: code => integer scalar
code <- 1

# Try this:  table1 => data.frame
table1 <- dbGetQuery(
  conn = connection, 
  statement = paste0(
    "SELECT * FROM database WHERE YEAR IN (",
    paste0(
      years, 
      collapse = ","
    ), 
    ") AND SYSTEM != 'G' AND CODE = '", 
    code,
    "'"
  )
)
```

Dummy input data:

```
# Generate some dummy data: years => integer vector
years <- seq(from = 2000, to = 2022, by = 1)
```